# Find limit of $\frac{|x|^3 y^2+|x|y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to show that $\lim_{{x\choose y}\to { 0 \choose 0}} \frac{|x|^3 y^2+|x|y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = 0$. But I cannot figure out the trick you need to find an upper estimation which goes to $0$. Do you have any hints?

**EDIT**:

I think I got it:

$\lim_{{x\choose y}\to { 0 \choose 0}} \frac{|x|^3 y^2+|x|y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2} =  \lim_{{x\choose y}\to { 0 \choose 0}} \frac{|x|^3 y^2}{(x^4+2x^2 y^2 +y^4)} +\lim_{{x\choose y}\to { 0 \choose 0}} \frac{|x|y^4}{(x^4+2x^2 y^2 +y^4)}\leq \lim_{{x\choose y}\to { 0 \choose 0}} \frac{|x|^3 y^2}{x^2 y^2}+\lim_{{x\choose y}\to { 0 \choose 0}} \frac{|x|y^4}{y^4}=\lim_{{x\choose y}\to { 0 \choose 0}} |x|+ \lim_{{x\choose y}\to { 0 \choose 0}} |x|=0.$

What do you think?

Comment: Yes my apporach seems a little bit overcomplicated but it was the only thing that came to my mind. The other answers are clearer.

Comment: I think that your notaton is a little bit overcomplicated but the method is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$\frac{|x|^3 y^2+|x|y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=|y|\cdot\frac{|x||y|}{x^2+y^2}. $$

Comment: @Robert Z, thanks for the hint. I dont know why but I didn't see that :S. Following your hint I get: $$\frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{|x|y^2}{y^2}=|x|.$$ Hence, the limit is $0$.

Comment: @Philipp Well done. You may also use the fact that $\frac{|x||y|}{x^2+y^2}\leq 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine indeed

$$\frac{|x|^3 y^2+|x|y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \le\frac{|x|^3 y^2}{x^2y^2}+\frac{|x|y^4}{y^4}=2|x| \to 0$$

as an alternative by polar coordinates we have

$$\frac{|x|^3 y^2+|x|y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=r \cdot f(\theta) \to 0$$

since $f(\theta)$ is bounded.

Comment: Let's see if I have understood you right. If I set $\Vert{x\choose y}\Vert<1$ using polar coordinates I get $x=r~ cos(\varphi)$ and $y=r~sin(\varphi)$ where $r<1$. Hence, $$\frac{r^5 cos(\varphi)^3 sin(\varphi)^2+r^5 cos(\varphi)sin(\varphi)^4}{r^4(cos(\varphi)^2+sin(\varphi)^2)^2}=\frac{r^5(cos(\varphi)^3 sin(\varphi)^2+cos(\varphi)sin(\varphi)^4)}{r^4((1)^2)^2}=r(cos(\varphi)^3 sin(\varphi)^2+cos(\varphi)sin(\varphi)^4).$$Let $f(\varphi)=cos(\varphi)^3 sin(\varphi)+cos(\varphi)sin(\varphi)^4$. How do I know that the limit is $0$? It might be that $f$ attains $\frac{1}{r}$.What do you think?

Comment: @Philipp Since both $\sin$ and $ \cos$ are bounded between $-1$ and $1$ then $-2\le f(\theta)\le 2$. The key point is that in polar coordinates the denominator isqual to $1$.

Comment: btw, I don't understand why someone downvoted this answer!?

Comment: @Philipp The first version was a bit confusing indeed but now it seems it was helpful to you. That's fine. Thanks Bye

Comment: yes, it gave me a nice view on that problem using polar coordinates, thx :)

Comment: @Philipp In some cases polar coordinates are indeed very helpful to have an insight  about what is going on. In this case your method seems the best one to me.

Comment: +1)  it is indeed a nice answer.